# how to use jump to a specific div of current page in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How do i convert this to codeigniter?

my php code for calling link is this

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php?option=register">Register Here</a>
<li><a href="index.php?option=login">Login</a>
</ul>
```

When I call this this specific link will be called.

```
<?php

@$opt = $_GET['option'];

if($opt=="") { 

    include('register.php');
    error_reporting(1);

} else {

   switch($opt) {

   case 'register':
             include('register.php');
             break;

    case 'login':
             include('login.php');
             break;

    }
}
```

But I don't know how to do it in code igniter.
please help me

Comment: My suggest pls learn how to load the view file in codeIgniter

Comment: i know how to load view instead of include i used  '$this->load->view('login');' but only the default page opens. The next code doesn't works

Comment: Note: Next time please check before you accept answer as @Anvar Pk looks like copied my code. I was first to post answer.

Comment: Sorry sir for my mistake. I will check it for next time onwards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a controller like Welcome.php or something

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {
    // Load other data stuff.

    // You should autoload the url helper.
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $opt = $this->input->get('option');

    if($opt == "") { 

        $data['title'] = 'Register';

        $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view('register');
        $this->load->view('footer');   

        error_reporting(1);

    } else {

       switch($opt) {

       case 'register':

            $data['title'] = 'Register';

            $this->load->view('header', $data);
            $this->load->view('register');
            $this->load->view('footer');

            break;

        case 'login':

            $data['title'] = 'Login';

            $this->load->view('header', $data);
            $this->load->view('login');
            $this->load->view('footer');

            break;
        }
    }


}
```

Config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

URI

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

To this

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

And then you can enable

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

And use the built in codeigniter query strings.

Then you would use a link like

```
<li><?php echo anchor('c=welcome&option=register', 'Register');?></li>
```

The letter c mean controller in codeigniter query string but you can change that in config.php

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: @RemyaR `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` shouldn't be changed if (as [docs](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L160) say) reprecussions are not considered well. Query string will work either leaving it with default value. Read [here](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2) about characters in URI.

Comment: Since there is still bad advice, I d-voted. It is bad practice and particulary someone new to CI hadn't be offered. I tried to fix it through edit, but there wasn't belief that security issue is not much important. In his (or your) values system security should be top priority (especially if there is no any gain with lowering security level). Something like this I already explained trying to edit answer. Also I am curious to hear why it is considered as good idea, although without any default values change query strings can be applied as well.

Comment: @Tpojka I have now modified answer